# android assets sizes and dpi for 55" mega display

Tags: android, dpi

I am trying to find the proper resolution for my images that should display on a large 55" display.It has a resolution of 1920x1080px. Can support 4k medias too.

I have placed my assets content in

I have been provided with a 2500 x 2500 px Illustrator vector shape.
these folders:

- mdpi  165x165
- hdpi   246 x 246px
- xhdpi   325x 325 px
- xxhdpi   490 x 490px
- xxxhdpi   652 x 652

The problem is I keep getting pixeled graphics on my 55 inch android display.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Vector shapes (Android Vector Drawables) you will only have a single image resource that fits all resolutions.  You can put that in the `res/drawable` folder.

Otherwise, the xxxhdpi bucket is the proper place to put your highest resolution images if you are using non-vector assets (either png or jpeg).

Comment: What should be the size in pixel for the png to be in this folder for a 55" display

Comment: It is a ratio of what your base image is...in this case xxxhdpi is 4 times the size of the mdpi (baseline) image.

Check this link for info.  https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities

Comment: I think you probably want to make all your resources larger, as it looks like you are using the correct ratio ---- make your baseline image larger, and see if this then scales the others up appropriately

Comment: When should I put assets in drawable-large, small, normal and xLarge folders